# Создать БД через форму input

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Подскажите как правильно дописать код, чтобы при создании БД, имя бралось из input?

Подобно phpMyAdmin.

[image: создать БД]

```
<?php //Создание БД
$db = mysql_connect ("localhost","root","") or die('Ошибка соединения: ' .mysql_error());
if(isset($_POST['createDB']))
{ 
    //$sql = mysql_query('CREATE DATABASE='.$_GET['nameDB']); 
    $sql = mysql_query('CREATE DATABASE my_db' );
    print ("База создана");
} 
?>
```

Comment: $sql = mysql_query('CREATE DATABASE $_POST[createDB]' );

Comment: Не используйте устаревшее расширение `mysql_`. Вместо него - `mysqli_` или `PDO`. Используйте подготовленные выражения, чтобы не страдать от SQL-инъекций. Даже не буду пытаться угадывать, зачем вам создавать базу через web-интерфейс.